# US debt and its creditors

Tags: debt, international

What does it mean when people say that China and others own US debt and are US creditors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The US Federal Government sells bonds so that it can live beyond it's means.  The Chinese government buy some of those bonds.

[This](https://www.businessinsider.com/who-we-owe-federal-debt-to-2013-10) article is six years old, and the numbers are much bigger now, but shows how the debt is distributed.

[image]

Comment: Which means that the creditors needs dollars to start with?

Comment: Which we shovel into China by the shipload.  https://www.census.gov/foreign-trade/balance/c5700.html

Comment: Right but that how it goes basically. They have dollars which they borrow to the goverment! How do they get the dollars? Buy trading of FXexchange?

Comment: "*How do they get the dollars?*" Did you follow the link in my comment about how **we shovel money to China by the shipload**, or was my comment unclear?

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear to me how these numbers are seattled if it is in dollar or yuan.

Comment: Understood.  The Chinese can either keep the dollars, or convert them to Yuan, at their pleasure and discretion.